# How to move folders and update an MS Access field in my table accordingly?

Tags: vba, ms-access, filesystems

I need to create an MS Access Button like in script below 
that moves subfolders of a folder to another folder and 
update an MS Access field in my table (query) accordingly.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Here is the image that describes my issue IN DETAILS:

[image: Details Screenshot]

Maybe it is possible to just update the script below.

---

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Access constants
Private Const A_INCOMING_ORDERS = "a_Incoming_Orders"
Private Const q_20_Wait = "q_20_Wait"
Private Const q_20_ACT = "q_20_ACT"
Private Const order_int_ID = "order_int_ID"
Private Const order_stage = "order_stage"

'Folders
Private Const FLD_DOWNLOADS = "d:\==Orders1290\10-1-Downloads\"
Private Const FLD_WAIT = "d:\==Orders1290\10-2-0-Wait\"
Private Const FLD_WAIT_90 = "d:\==Orders1290\10-2-1-Wait_PSD-90\"

----------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub Ctl10_20___10_30_Click()
  Dim FSO As Object
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  'Get all files in FLD_WAIT
  Dim fileList As Object
  Set fileList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim oFile As Object, baseName As String
  For Each oFile In FSO.GetFolder(FLD_WAIT).Files
    baseName = FSO.GetBaseName(oFile.Name)
    If fileList.Exists(baseName) Then
      MsgBox _
        "Existing: " & fileList.Item(baseName) & vbLf & vbLf & _
        "Duplicate: " & oFile.Path, vbExclamation, _
        "Duplicate Found - while collecting file names in { FLD_WAIT }."
    Else
      fileList.Add baseName, oFile.Path
    End If
  Next

  'Open Recordset
  Dim rs As Recordset
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(q_20_ACT)
    If (Not Err.Number = 0) Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Recordset: " & q_20_ACT: Exit Sub
    If (rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF) Then: MsgBox "No data in recordset!", vbCritical, "Recordset: " & q_20_ACT: Exit Sub
  On Error GoTo 0

  'Move files in query matching order_int_ID
  Dim idName, dFolder As String, cont As Integer
  While (Not rs.EOF)
    idName = rs.Fields(order_int_ID).Value
    If TypeName(idName) = "String" Then
      If fileList.Exists(idName) Then
        dFolder = FLD_PROCESS_PSD & "\" & idName
        If FSO.FolderExists(dFolder) Then
          cont = MsgBox( _
            "{ FLD_PROCESS_PSD } already has a folder in it matching an { ORDER_INT_ID } of: " & idName & vbLf & vbLf & "Skip & continue with the next file?", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, _
            "While creating folders for { ORDER_INT_ID } files")
          If cont = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
        Else
          FSO.CreateFolder dFolder
          FSO.MoveFile fileList.Item(idName), dFolder & "\"
          rs.Edit: rs.Fields(order_stage) = "3_in_ACTION": rs.Update
        End If
      Else
        cont = MsgBox( _
          "No files found in { FLD_WAIT } that match an { ORDER_INT_ID } of: " & idName & vbLf & vbLf & "Skip & continue with the next file?", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, _
          "While moving { ORDER_INT_ID } files")
        If cont = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
      End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
  Wend
  rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Which part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: This code works perfectly! I need another code that transfers folders as described on the image above. I thought this code could be updated to meet my requirements.